# Upgrade existing Google spreadsheet to New Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I keep getting the message on my Google spreadsheet that I'm using the old spreadsheet. There is an option to create the new Google sheet, but no option to upgrade the existing.

Please check this image.

[image: Upgrade Google Sheet Message]

Even the sheets I create now is the new Google sheet by default. Please let me know whether there is an option to upgrade the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the old Doc as an XLSX, then upload and convert to Google doc version, it upgrades the doc. I haven't found anything it doesn't keep yet. It even kept my named ranges.

[EDIT] I did have to "tickle" some functions by removing, then re-adding the = sign in front. Or double-clicking the cell, then just hitting enter. Maybe I just wasn't patient, but the majority of my complex spreadsheet was still functioning after the procedure above.

Comment: please find my [comment](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58697/upgrade-existing-google-spreadsheet-to-new-google-sheet/69119#comment46836_58698) posted for the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is not possible to update an old sheet to a new one. But:

- you can create a new Google sheet, name it e.g. "oldname (new)" and
- copy every tab from the old sheet to the new one via right click on tab and "copy to..."

Comment: That's not practical in my case. My Drive is full with spreadsheets.

Comment: As far as I know there is no other possibility to upgrade at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to [Eric Koleda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702875/eric-koleda) about this, and his [response](https://twitter.com/erickoleda/status/917736662515568641) was as follows:

> "There aren't any more old Google Sheets left, they've all been
>   upgraded to new Google Sheets by now."

So it appears the old spreadsheets were upgraded silently and en masse at some point.